# Inserting from two other tables into a third

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I'm trying to insert a small batch of rows (<10) at once into a table. The data is in a table-valued parameter, but I need to add some extra columns to it that are common to all the rows before inserting it. I've tried two ways of doing this:

```
INSERT INTO endTable
([col1],[col2],[commoncol1],[commoncol2])
SELECT
t.col1, t.col2, @CommonValue1, @CommonValue2
FROM startTable t
```

I've also tried to do it by putting the common variables into a temporary table variable, and then cross joining it with startTable, like this:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE([temp1],[temp2])
INSERT INTO @tempTable(temp1,temp2) VALUES (@CommonValue1, @CommonValue2)

INSERT INTO endTable
([col1],[col2],[commoncol1],[commoncol2])
SELECT
a.col1, a.col2, b.temp1, b.temp2
FROM startTable a CROSS JOIN @tempTable b
```

Both of these attempts give the same error if and only if startTable has multiple rows:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I was hoping to accomplish these inserts without resorting to a loop, but I'm not incredibly familiar with SQL, so I don't know if I'm out of luck, or if I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you don't have any of those operators (=, !=, <, <= , >, >=) in your first query, the problem must lie somewhere else.  The first version should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `INSERT` statement does not have a subquery, the error message doesn't make sense.  My guess is that you have a trigger on `endTable` that is throwing the error.

Run the following query to see if you have any triggers on `endTable`.  If you do, then you will need to inspect the SQL in the trigger to see why it is throwing the error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.triggers 
WHERE parent_id = OBJECT_ID(N'endTable')
```

Comment: Thank you! Having never heard of triggers before (I'm new at this), I would never have been able to find it. Looks like I'm using a loop, because I'm not modifying this.