# Is this the correct way to insert query result from two tables into a third table

Tags: qt, sqlite

I've searched around ([Inserting from two other tables into a third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583102/inserting-from-two-other-tables-into-a-third)) but am not seeing a clear answer to this simple question. The code below seems to work but it is clumsy and I'm wondering if I am working too hard.

The task:

INSERT *id of keyword "blue" FROM table "keywords"* and *id of image FROM table "images" WHERE  id = 1* as FOREIGN_KEYS into third table "images_keywords" The table "images_keywords" has only these two fields and both are defined as FOREIGN_KEYS.

I'm wondering:

- Is how I am doing this inefficient (or just plan wrong...)?
- Am I handling the FOREIGN_KEYS
  correctly?

---

```
void MainWindow::on_addKeywordBtn_clicked()
{
    // find keyword = "blue"
    QSqlQuery keywordQuery(db);
    keywordQuery.prepare("SELECT id, keyword FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
    keywordQuery.addBindValue(QString("blue"));
    keywordQuery.exec();

    // find image with id = 1
    QSqlQuery imageQuery(db);
    imageQuery.prepare("SELECT id FROM images WHERE id = ?");
    imageQuery.addBindValue(1);
    imageQuery.exec();

    QSqlQuery insertQuery(db);
    while (keywordQuery.next() && imageQuery.next()) {

        insertQuery.prepare( "INSERT INTO images_keywords (image_id, keyword_id) VALUES (:image_id, :keyword_id)" );
        insertQuery.bindValue( ":image_id", imageQuery.record().value("id").toInt());
        insertQuery.bindValue( ":keyword_id", keywordQuery.record().value("id").toInt());
        bool result= insertQuery.exec();

        if (!result)  qDebug() <<  insertQuery.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does each image and keyword have a one-to-one match? The way you have this setup now, it won't allow for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @CameronTinker - Not sure what you mean. This is simple Qt/Sqlite learning project: tagging images with keywords. So far 3 tables: images, keywords and images_keywords. The last uses Foreign Keys: image id and keyword id. Each image can have multiple keywords and each keyword can be used any number of times. So an "apple" image could have "green" & "red" as key words, resulting in 2 entries in the images_keyword table: appleID, greenID; appleID redID. Does that sound wrong?

Comment: No problem about this being a learning application. I'm just sharing that your implementation will work, but only with a one-to-one relationship. A one-to-one relationship means that for one item, it is directly related to one other item. If you wanted to add green, red, and yellow as keywords to apples, you would need to have a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. The code in my answer below demonstrates how to achieve the one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @CameronTinker - oh, I get what you are saying. Yes, my code example is just junk code using hard-coded values to get the Sqlite syntax working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct mostly and I'm assuming that you've already populated your keywords and images tables. I just have a couple of suggestions to improve on your process.

When doing any data interactions in my applications, I create a data access layer class, usually named DAL, for easier code re-use. If you have objects representing keywords and images, you could pass objects to each method and perform the CRUD operations on the objects themselves. Think of this as sort of a very rudimentary object relational mapper.

In the code below, you might not need GetImage if you already have the image ID. You would simply just pass along the image ID into InsertImageKeyword after retrieving the keyword ID.

```
int DAL::GetKeyword(QString keyword)
{
    // get ID
    QSqlQuery keywordQuery(db);
    keywordQuery.prepare("SELECT id FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
    keywordQuery.addBindValue(image);
    keywordQuery.exec();
    int id = -1;
    if(keywordQuery.next())
        id = keywordQuery.record().value("id").toInt();
    return id;
}

int DAL::GetImage(QString image)
{
    // get ID
    QSqlQuery imageQuery(db);
    imageQuery.prepare("SELECT id FROM images WHERE image = ?");
    imageQuery.addBindValue(image);
    imageQuery.exec();
    int id = -1;
    if(imageQuery.next())
        id = imageQuery.record().value("id").toInt();
    return id;
}

bool DAL::InserImageKeyword(int imageId, int keywordId)
{
    QSqlQuery insertQuery(db);
    insertQuery.prepare( "INSERT INTO images_keywords (image_id, keyword_id) VALUES (:image_id, :keyword_id)" );
    insertQuery.bindValue( ":image_id", imageId);
    insertQuery.bindValue( ":keyword_id", keywordId);

    bool result= insertQuery.exec();

    if (!result)  
        qDebug() <<  insertQuery.lastError().text();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Right now I am just working in a scratch project to figure out the Sqlite cmds but will need that sort of layer when handling multiple modes of user input.